# Power Query PREVIOUSDAY over weekends, holidays

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a table with columns date, warehouse, stock code, units. The date is linked to a calendar table, which has a true/false column which days are 'valuation days', meaning weekdays and non holiday days.

I've created a column with

```
previous day units =calculate(sum('Table'[Units]),
        PREVIOUSDAY('Calendar'[Date]),
                                ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[Product],'Table'[Warehouse]))
```

That column succesfully shows the previous day's stock for each warehouse / product combination, but on Mondays it compares stock levels to Sunday, which doesn't have an entry in Table, and so is zero. I need to compare Monday to Friday.

There's lots of similar queries, but I can't for the life of me find a solution that works when I have this warehouse / product  combination in my table.

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvGgS.png)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure i found myself the solution. I created another custom column which used LOOKUPVALUE to bring the a field 'PrevValuation Day' into 'Table' and then used

```
=calculate(sum('Table'[Units]),
        filter(ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[Product],'Table'[Warehouse]),'Table'[Date]=EARLIER('Table'[PrevValuationDay])
))
```

and that seems to work.